# Percentage Validation

Tags: ios, swift, nsregularexpression

in my project there is percentage field in which user can add percentage. I want to allow user to enter valid exam percentage like **85.85** instead of 100.00000 or any other. percentage should be of 4 digit and after 2 digit there is **.** after that there will be 2 digits. Percentage Always be like **83.05%**. i already allow only digits. so user can enter only digit. Regular express will also be accepted.
Thanking you in advance

Comment: Try this: `^\d{2}.\d{2}$`  NB: Just a guess

Comment: @LalKrishna You are right. But in swift we have mention like 
`let regExp_Percentage = "^[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}$"`
Thank you your Answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if string == "" {
         return true    // back arrow clicked
    }
    if textField.text?.count == 5 {
         return false
    }
    if textField.text?.count == 2 {

       textField.text = "\(textField.text!)."  /// insert dot
    }
    return true
}
```

with

```
self.textfield.delegate = self
```

//

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , UITextFieldDelegate {
```

Comment: It works like charm. you saved my day..!!
Thank you so much. :)